# How to apply PCA using flow interface before AutoML

Tags: h2o

I'm not a skilled programmer. Have been using the flow user interface to try building some models in autoML.

I understand that the open source software doesn't do much in terms of adjusting features since that function is left to the commercial product.

I was wondering, are there easy steps I can take with the flow interface to help with improving features?

For example, I have one data set with something like 800 features. I think many of them are duplicative / correlated.

Would it be possible to reduce/collapse these by using the PCA model built into flow?

If so, could someone offer some tips / steps on how to do it? I'm unsure of how to pull this off?

I assume it would be something like:

load train data set -> create pca model -> use pca model to reduce number of features -> run autoML on resulting data set

then

how to apply the same to score a testing data set?

does this make sense?

Thanks!